# This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT
    "0" & "-" & a.G_DEPT AS LEVEL_NBR,
    "G: Omni_Dept" AS LEVEL_,
    "OMNI" AS CHANNEL_, 
    a.DIV,
    a.DIV_DESC,
    a.DEPT,
    a.DEPT_DESC,
    NULL AS COL1,
    NULL AS COL2,
    NULL AS COL3,
    NULL AS COL4, 
    NULL AS COL5,
    NULL AS COL6,
    NULL AS COL7,
    NULL AS COL8,
    NULL AS COL9,
    NULL AS COL10, 
    ROUND(AVG(a.NET_SLS_CST),2) AS NET_SLS_CST,
    ROUND(AVG(a.NET_SLS_OWN),2) AS NET_SLS_OWN, 
    ROUND(AVG(a.FIRST_SLS_TKT),2) AS FIRST_SLS_TKT, 
    ROUND(AVG(a.NET_SLS_TKT),2) AS NET_SLS_TKT, 
    SUM(a.OH_U) AS OH_U,
    SUM(a.OO_U) AS OO_U,
    SUM(a.NET_SLS) AS NET_SLS, 
    **SUM(CDbl(a.NET_UNITS)+CDbl(a.OH_U)) AS SO**
FROM
    ADMIN_DATA_TBL AS a
WHERE
    a.DEPT=[:hierNbr]
    AND
    a.STATUS=[:stat]
    AND
    a.TYLY='TY'
GROUP BY
    "0" & "-" & a.G_DEPT,
    a.DIV,
    a.DIV_DESC,
    a.DEPT,
    a.DEPT_DESC;
```

I am having trouble with this statement (refer to statement in bold/asterisk, `SUM(CDbl(a.NET_UNITS)+CDbl(a.OH_U)) AS SO`) it is giving me this error:

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements.

I tried to remove the casting, but still same issue.

Comment: As `SUM` and `+` are commutative operations, you could just do `SUM(a.NET_UNITS)` and do the final addition with `SUM(a.OH_U)` in your application code, outside of SQL - or in an outer `SELECT` query. Of course, the **best** solution is to stop using MS Access and switch to a less braindead database engine :)

Comment: Also, why do you have so many `NULL AS COLn` expressions?

Comment: Please delete all code not relevant to your problem, eg all select expressions except the last and the `where` clause and possibly some of the problem expression. Experiment to see how small you can make the query yet still show the problem and put that reduced query in your question.. how do you know the last selected column is the problem anyway?

Comment: I tested SQL without WHERE clause and the query works. Nothing wrong with that Sum() expression. Sample raw data as text table could be helpful.

Comment: @Dai - If you want to help people with their Access questions that's great, but please stop using your responses as opportunities to editorialize about how much you dislike the product.